# General expressions in file I/O loop with strings and floats

Tags: python, file-io, syntax

I am hoping some body can help me understand how this code is working -- I am reading in a tab delimitted txt file that has a header with the title of variable, followed by col 0 = id, and subsequent columns = to a value of N/A or a float value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

argvstuff = sys.argv


filename = argvstuff[1]
outputname = argvstuff[2]

df_handle = open(filename, "r")
wf_handle = open(outputname, "w")

rawheaderLine = df_handle.readline()
wf_handle.write(rawheaderLine)

for rawline in df_handle:
        line = rawline.strip()
        lineparts = line.split("\t")
        id = lineparts[0]
        yes_or_no = lineparts[1]
        heart1 = (lineparts[2])
        liver1 = (lineparts[3])
        lung1 = (lineparts[4])
        brain1 = (lineparts[5])


if(yes_or_no == "Y" and str(lineparts[2:]) != "NA"):
                if((kidney1) and (kidney2) and (kidney3) <= -1.5):
                        if((liver1) and (liver2) and (liver3) > 1.5):


                                wf_handle.write(f"{id} \t {yes_or_no} \t {heart1} \t {liver1} \t {lung1} \t {brain1} \t {kidney1} \n")
```

If I only have the first if statement, it will correctly print all of the indices of the line list, with the whole line such that yes_or_no = Y and no indices have a 'NA' as the value. I am assuming that now that I have sorted it based on that, that all subsequent readlines will not have 'NA' as the value, and will instead have floats as the value, and will have yes_or_no equal to Y and I can begin to perform my next if statements on it. However, I get a type error. I have tried converting these to float() but I get the same error, for some reason it seems like 'NA' values are still getting through my if loop -- Where am I going wrong here? Thank you

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Here is the input file example

```
    id     yes_or_no    heart1    kidney1    liver1    brain1   
thing1    Y    0.00061    0.5567    NA    2.51
thing2    N    0.00511    1.5    2.4    0.0004
thing3    N    NA    0.05    2.025    1.511
```

Comment: This question is very difficult to follow. Would be very helpful if the data file was included. Further, at a glance, the conditional logic ```str(lineparts[2:]) != "NA"``` is probably not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: And the error is created because one or all of the variables <kidney1> ..2  ..  or 3 are string variables, which do not use math comparators the same way as integers and floats. If you are certain that those variables contain numbers, you need to cast the values to float, simply by coding ```float(kidney1)``` etc.

Comment: Also also, I don't believe the logical statement ```if((kidney1) and (kidney2) and (kidney3) <= -1.5)```  is what you want. Use ```and``` to separate conditional statements, not join variables together into the same conditional statement. e.g.  ```if float(kidney1) <= -1.5  and  float(kidney2) <= -1.5  and  float(kidney3) <= -1.5: ```
\br

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if((kidney1) and (kidney2) and (kidney3) <= -1.5):
```

You probably intend to check whether each individual value is less than -1.5:

```
if (kidney1 <= -1.5) and (kidney2 <= -1.5) and (kidney3 <= 1.5):
```

This will fail if the kidney values are strings, which they most likely are if you read them from a file. You can avoid the error by casting them to floats:

```
if float(kidney1) <= -1.5 and float(kidney2) <= -1.5 and float(kidney3) <= 1.5:
```

Even if you cast your kidney values as floats, you'll run into trouble in your original version because the `<=` operation doesn't distribute over the three kidney values. Your original statement is the same as:

```
if (kidney1 and kidney2 and kidney3) <= -1.5
```

When you use `and` over a sequence of values, Python will keep iterating through them until it hits the end of the sequence or sees a "falsey" value. For strings, the empty string is falsey, while any non-empty string is truthy. For floats, 0 is falsey and anything else (even NaN) is truthy. It's worth playing around with this in the console to build an intuition:

```
>>> "hello" and "world"
"world"
>>> "hello" and "world" and "" and "more" and "strings"
""
>>> (1 and 3) <= 1.5
False
>>> (3 and 1) <= 1.5
True
```

Comment: So I am guaranteed to hit another 'NA' value which will automatically falsify that operation ``` 
if float(kidney1) <= -1.5 and float(kidney2) <= -1.5 and float(kidney3) <= 1.5:
```
How do I overcome this, when I know a value in the list will be a string (NA) but don't know when/where it is coming. How do I prepare for this? Should I be initializing a new list in order to garuntee that they are floats, and not strings?

Comment: What do you want to do if, say, kidney3 is NA? Do you want to check whether kidney1 and kidney2 are both less than 1.5 and ignore kidney3, or do you want the check to be False?

Comment: If any value is NA I do not want that line printed, because that experiment will be essentially void. So kidney1 kidney2 kidney3 would not be relevant and it would go to the next line. Kidney1 kidney2 and kidney3 are only printed if all of the values, individually, are less than 1.5

Comment: You could check for that first and only check the float values if you don't see an NA: `if 'NA' not in (kidney1, kidney2, kidney3) and float(kidney1) <= -1.5 and float(kidney2) <= -1.5 ...`

Comment: So I guess my question is, why doesn't my first if statement garuntee that any subsequent value is not 'NA'? I think this is the assumption that is confusing me. I thought I already did check and garuntee that subsequent values are not equal to NA.

Comment: `lineparts[2:]` is a list. If you cast a list to a string, the string will include the `[` and `]` that identify it as a list, so `str(["hello"]) != "hello"`. You should check whether 'NA' is in the list, instead of converting the list to a string and checking whether that string is equal to 'NA'